# Setting the last background image as the default

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have added four images and by default i have background image. I used a button to change the background randomly. It is panorama page and i just want my app to save the last state(i.e **to remember the last background image**) and if my app is activated then the last image should be the default background image. Since i have already added some images to my app so i think this doesn't need Isolated Storage. What i need is if the current background image(imguri) is **bg1.jpg**, and if i exit the app and if i relaunch it then the default background image should be **bg1.jpg**. Need help!

```
private void BackgroundBrowser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string imguri = "";

    click_count = click_count % 5;
    switch (click_count)
    {
        case 0: imguri = "Image/bg.jpg"; break;
        case 1: imguri = "Image/bg1.jpg"; break;
        case 2: imguri = "Image/bg3.jpg"; break;
        case 3: imguri = "Image/bg2.jpg"; break;
        case 4: imguri = ""; break;
    }
    click_count++;

    var app = Application.Current as App;
    app.appBmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imguri, UriKind.Relative));
    ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
    imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
    imageBrush.Opacity = 0.7;
    imageBrush.ImageSource = app.appBmp;
    this.LayoutRoot.Background = imageBrush;
    app.appbrush = imageBrush;
    app.backchanged = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Application or User Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx). Go to project properties and click the Settings tab. Then create a setting name LastImagePath with String as a type:

[image]

Now just before this line:

```
var app = Application.Current as App;
```

Add this to save the path to the LastImagePath settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.LastImagePath = imguri;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To load the last image, you can load up the setting wherever you want like this:

```
if (!(Properties.Settings.Default.LastImagePath == null))
   imgpath = Properties.Settings.Default.LastImagePath;
```

Comment: I am using Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 not the Ultimate or Professional version. So i don't have any settings tabs in my VS2010. Is the above can be done via codes?

Comment: @RaghavMac It is available on the Windows Phone too, just not in the same way. It uses IsolatedStorage to accomplish this. Please take a look at this: [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx). It uses almost the same approach as I used in my post.

Answer (score 0):

you need save the last image name in a file when your application exit and read image name from the file and load it when your application start again. I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` in a similar manner to what DelegateX has shown. Mind that regardless of how do you 'save' your setting, it **will** be stored in the isolated storage space. It is just nicely wrapped and hidden as a Properties/ApplicationSettings/Session etc proeprties or class names, but in fact the data will land on ISO, and will evaporate when you uninstall the app from the device.

Answer (score 0):

All items stored in the User/Application settings need to be serializable (there is a note at the bottom of the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263230.aspx)). Learn more about serialization [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinStoreAppSaveCollection-bed5d6e6).